# Como cambiar de directorio en WSL Ubuntu en Windows 11?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, wsl

he instalado ubuntu desde la Microsoft Store, pero al momento de entrar a una carpeta desde la consola de ubuntu, esta no cambia, ya probé con cd pero no me deja, Alguien me podría ayudar?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observaciones generales:

1. Considera que es una distribución de Linux.
2. Estás en Bash, no en el tradicional CMD de Windows.

Utiliza los siguientes comandos:

```
cd /mnt/
ls -la
cd d/
```

Si vas a programar en WSL con herramientas y/o lenguajes instalados en él, te sugiero que utilices carpetas dentro del entorno WSL, como `/home/AlgunaCarpetaAqui`. Por experiencia te digo que si vas a trabajar desde Windows, utiliza VS Code + La extensión de `WSL Remote`. Tener base de datos en WSL está en una red diferente del localhost de Windows. Ten estas ideas en mente y te ahorrarás frustraciones.